# Can I change the "lightning-record-form"?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-record-form

Here is my code:

```
           <div if:true={showStepOne}>
                <div role="dialog" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open ">
                    <div class="slds-modal__container">
                        <header class="slds-modal__header">
                            <h1 class="slds-text-heading--medium">New Work Type</h1>
                        </header>
                        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                            <lightning-record-form
                                object-api-name="WorkType"
                                fields={fieldsFormStepOne}
                                onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
                            </lightning-record-form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
            </div>
```

Is it possible to change the functionality of the "Save" button, remove the "Cancel" button, change the location of the "Auto-Create Service Appointment" element?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to customize the functionality, look and feel of the form, you are better off using the [lightning-record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation). You will have greater flexibility as to ordering the fields and placing, adding/removing buttons.